# Difference between photodiodes and avalanche photodiodes

Tags: semiconductor-physics, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

I'd say I'm quite aware of how avalanche photodiodes work but I'm unsure of how usual photodiodes work respectively how they differ from each other.

Let's bring it down to: APDs are able to detect single photons and their produced signal corresponds to the amount of energy deposited within them.
How is it in case of photodiodes?

Answer (score 1):

Both diodes rely on the generation of electrons and holes in the diode by photons. In the "normal" photodiode, the current is just the generation current, i.e., the current corresponding to the generated charge carriers in the diode. The avalanche photo diode, uses the avalanche charge carrier multiplication process in the high electric field of the depletion zone of the diode. There a single generated charge carrier is so much accelerated that it can generate another electron hole pair by impact ionization and the thus generated charge carriers are again accelerated to generate electron-hole pairs, producing an avalanche of electron-hole pairs. This avalanche ionization process leads to a huge amplification of the photon induced generation current, which gives a great sensitivity advantage to the APD as compared to the photo diode.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In case of the regular photodiodes, could one say the signal corresponds strictly to the deposited energy? Or is it rather the number of photons?

Answer (score 1):

**The avalanche and standard diodes differs in their structure, mechanism, applications and responsitivity.**

### Structure

With respect to a standard photodiode, an additional layer is added in which secondary electron–hole pairs are generated through impact ionization.

[image]

### Mechanism

The **Impact Ionization** that occurs in an APD makes it different from a standard photodiode. This built-in mechanism of APD multiplies the number of charges generated by a single photon resulting in a much larger current.

### Responsivity

The responsivity of standard p–i–n photodiodes is limited by its maximum value given by Rmax = q/hν for η = 1. Avalanche photodiode (APDs) can have much larger values of R, as they are designed to provide an internal current gain

### Applications

Due to the multiplication of charges APDs are more sensitive to single photons compare to photodiodes, and also they have better noise performance which makes them useful in applications like low light imaging, single photon counting and lidar.

In general p-i-n photodiode is less responsive than APD but with lower noise level and can be more accurate, While APD is more responsive and have higher gain but with higher noise level. So the choice of either device would depend on the specific application and the desired trade-off between sensitivity, speed, and noise. Avalanche Photodiodes are often used in applications such as lidar and time-resolved spectroscopy. Standard Pin photodiodes are often used in applications such as optical communications and light detection.

Comment: Thank you very much as well! I probably should have addressed this in the main question above: To what does the generated diode's signal correlate? Energy and/or number of photons? Or is it somehow independent from that? In other words: Does the signal strength correlate e.g. with the energy and or number of photons or so?

Comment: The current generated by any photodiode is directly proportional to the number of photons (light intensity) that are absorbed. The current generated by the incident light intensity is equal to the product of the incident photon flux (number of photons per unit area per unit time), the absorption coefficient of the material (wavelength dependant), and the active area of the photodiode. It's just electrons are multiplied in Avalanche.

Comment: I advise you to study photodiodes in sequence of PN > PIN > Avalanche > SPAD (single photon avalanche diodes). not otherwise

Comment: Ok, thanky you! But in case of an APD the signal is strongly energy correlated, or not? May sound weird now but I worked with APDs for a while but only with them, that's why I'm kind of familiar with them but lack the understanding of how to separate them from regular photodiodes. This is the reason why I try to understand the topic from the odd backward direction..

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by energy here. Energy of light incident on photodiode? or energy of avalanche region that multiplies the generated current? The avalanche is just advanced form of standard photodiode. If you know how an avalanche works and don't know how a standard one works, prolly you don't know both. Are you usually looking at datasheets of diodes (referring to your energy correlation)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I really mean the energy of the photon respectively the energy it deposits within the photodiode. Yeah, might true, maybe I add something more background: My department uses mainly APDs but for some purposes we also use regular photodiodes and a colleague recently told me that the regular photodiodes generate only binary signals like "bright" or "dark". And I don't get this especially as I'm (only) used to APDs where the signal strongly correlates to the deposited energy. From my understanding, this must be valid for regular photodiodes as well, or not..?!

Comment: Thanks for explaination. I guess your colleague meant regular light sensors/switches or LDR switch. A photodiode is a type of light sensor. A junction in photodiode is made to generate different current for different light intensities. Please check more here.
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/io/io_4.html